# WebRTC cordova plugin in ionic 3 angular 4

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, webrtc, ionic3

I have worked on a video conferencing hybrid app back when ionic 2 was still in beta. I developed it in ionic 1 with a few tweaks to make it work. Working now with ionic 3 and angular 4, I am struggling to find an officially supported WebRTC cordova plugin for my ionic app. Does anyone have an idea if the plugin would be officially supported soon? If not , what are the best options to use? Thanks guys!

Comment: Hey @Floyd1256 found any thing for WebRTC for android and ios???

Comment: I actually ended up using the `RTCPeerConnection` object for android, but I believe the `iosrtc` plugin is needed for integration on iOS

Comment: @Floyd1256 : that's correct about iosrtc, I tried to give a complete answer in the following post. Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 5):

On Android, WebRTC is supported since Webview v36 (Android 5 Lollipop and higher). See [this document](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview) for more information.

[This site](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Platform) provides data about the relative number of devices running a given version of the Android platform.

As you can see, you need to support a lot of different Android versions. I would advise you to use Crosswalk as an plugin for Cordova. Crosswalk bundles the app with an up-to-date Chrome webview that replaces the default Chrome webview of the Android device. So every Android device running the app have the exact same webview. This way old Android device can work with WebRTC, no more css fixes for older Chrome versions and no more performance problems. The downside is that Crosswalk & Cordova installed adds 58 MB of disk space. Cordova without Crosswalk adds 1,9 MB of disk space.

Using Crosswalk is very simple, just one line of code:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
```

WebRTC is supported since iOS 11. In october 2017 iOS 11 had a worldwide share of 41,99% according to [statcounter.com](http://gs.statcounter.com/os-version-market-share/ios/mobile-tablet/worldwide). If you visit the website you can also see the stats of your country.

So for iOS you definitely need a cordova plugin. I know two options:
 [iosrtc](https://github.com/BasqueVoIPMafia/cordova-plugin-iosrtc) and [phonertc](https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I note that crosswalk might not be necessary after looking at this [Android Device Dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) since the majority of devices are running versions newer than 4.4 . Concerning iOS, do you think phonertc is a bit outdated? or does it still work?

Comment: @Floyd1256 : You are welcome, nice to discuss this issue, since I have to make the same decision. If I look at the dashboard and count everything below 4.4, it is still 7,2%. I don't think Android 4.4 is supported, are you sure about that? And that is still 13,8%. But even if a very high percentage of the android device is supported, you still need to test all different versions, not? Is installing 58MB extra not worth it? And after a year or so, you can simply delete it with no effort. I'm curious about your opinion.

Comment: @Floyd1256 : You should also decide in which country's you app needs to run. I will first focus on the Netherlands, [looking here](http://gs.statcounter.com/android-version-market-share/mobile-tablet/netherlands/#monthly-201711-201711-bar) to get more data about the Netherlands (or whatever country). And if I press the button "Download Data (.csv)" I get more detailed information. If I select november 2017, I get 11,8% in the Netherlands android 4.4 and lower (much better score than world-wide).

Comment: @Floyd1256 : I am not sure phonertc is outdated, I didn't work with it yet.

Comment: @Floyd1256 : I have a test device Samsung Galaxy Tab3 8.0 inch (SM-T310) Android 4.4.2. I will do some tests later. I remember some part of my app was not working and I decided to install crosswalk. That was before WebRTC was involved.

Comment: It is indeed good to discuss such things, as we can benefit from each others' experiences. Actually some versions or variations of 4.4 have worked without the need to use crosswalk, but I guess it is a safer choice to have crosswalk installed. The thing is my guess is that devices running old versions would already have a hard time to use video capabilities (device heating up and battery drain). What do you think?

Comment: @Floyd1256 : my test device is a Samsung Galaxy Tab3 8.0 inch (SM-T310) Android 4.4.2. Pretty old but it works !!!